# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary in azure

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver

The python test are running successfully in local, but it gives error when I am executing it in Azure using Microsoft hosted Agents